# Search Products in Back Office by typing for example >=3

Tags: php, mysql, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

This may sound a basic question but I may be using the wrong approach to seek an answer for this.

How can I do a simple search for products in Prestashop Back-Office by using a value interval or something like ">=3" ou "<3"

For example I would like to query all produts that have more than 10 Units available. So I would expect to simply type ">10" in the quantity field and hit search, but it's not working out of the box.

I can create this query in mysql but is there an easier and faster solution to implement this without going to the tpl files or change controllers?

Comment: Can you put what have you tried so far? a taste of your code?

Comment: I'm currently looking at AdminProductsController.php and browsing here http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+HelperList+class to see If I can do something similar to what I've already done with Yii on other project, but isn't there a simple solution to this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid there is not simple solution to override the default behavior of the search tool of prestashop. But you could dig into `/classes/Search.php`.

By the way, the easiest way (IMHO) to handle this is to use the SQL manager of Prestashop :

Advance parameters -> SQL Manager -> Add new.

And then, give a name and build your custom SQL request.

i.e. :

SQL query name : Custom Select Product infos by quantity

SQL query :

```
SELECT  p.id_product, p.id_category_default, p.ean13, sa.quantity, p.price, p.wholesale_price, p.reference, p.active
FROM ps_product AS p
LEFT JOIN 
    ps_stock_available AS sa
ON sa.id_product = p.id_product
WHERE sa.id_product_attribute = 0
AND sa.quantity > 1000;
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any simple solution for this. As you figured out you'll have to deal with the `AdminProductsController` and `helperList` but this will be a really painful task.

An other approach would be to let the product admin tab as it is and manage your products with a Module. [StoreCommander](https://www.storecommander.com/en/sc-solo/258-store-commander-solo.html) is a powerful module that helps manage a lot of products on your store with advanced functionality and mass editing. It contains advanced filters that will allow you to search for products with quantity "> 10".

In [this documentation (in French)](https://www.storecommander.com/support/fr/index.php?controller=attachment&id_attachment=57) you can see at the bottom of page 9 this advanced filter being used.

(I should mention that I am not linked to this company, this module has just been the reference for Prestashop Addons for years and its clearly worth the money)